# String replace using Javascript regex "&" to "&amp;" while ignoring a Special Entities like "&#169;"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace "`&`" to "`&amp;`" globally in a html file.

```
var result = inputString.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
```

This is working fine, But the problem is that, "`&amp;`" also replacing in the html special entities code.

Example : `"&#169;"`

So, i want to ignore this while replacing.

Comment: Add some input strings and expected output

Comment: Use lookahead: `var result = inputString.replace(/&(?!#)/g, "&amp;");`

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead `?!`

Your regex should look something like this:

```
&(?!(\S)+;)
```